# Call model method in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, model, token, faye

This is my model in Ruby on Rails 3 project:

```
class Faye < ActiveRecord::Base
  def faye_chatroom_token_id
    a = Faye.find_by_sql("SELECT userid FROM chat WHERE id = #{current_profile.id}")
    Digest::MD5.hexdigest(a.first)
  end
end
```

I need to use it in javascript:

```
function broadcast(){
  var channel = **Hier I will call the model method**;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:9292/faye",
    data: 'message={"channel":"/'+channel+'/chatroom", "data":"1"}',
    dataType: "json",
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    crossDomain: true,
  });
}
```

Please, help me!

Comment: how(where) js renders?

Answer (score 0):

you have to render somewhere into html your `channel`

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :channel_id, @faye.faye_chatroom_token_id %>
```

and than just take it with

```
$('#channel_id').val();
```